# Find out what resources are not going over HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https

I have an ASP.NET site which should transport completely over HTTPS. However, in Google Chrome I get a warning that the page includes resources which are not secure. How can I find out which those resources are and why they wouldn't be going over HTTPS?

Comment: similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305538/how-do-i-figure-out-which-parts-of-a-web-page-are-encrypted-and-which-arent

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13760256/483588

Comment: Chrome Devtools > Network tab > right-click any column heading > click "Scheme"

Comment: This is also commonly seen when users embed url images in stackexchange posts, they use the http version instead of https.

Comment: I know this post is a little old but in case it helps anyone, there's a Desktop app you can run now to scan and report on mixed content issues found on a site: https://www.ecommerce.co.uk/httpschecker Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Usually this occurs because you are loading Images, javascript include files or external CSS files without using https. You can use a program such as FireBug: http://getfirebug.com/

FireBug will tell you how your elements are loading and which aren't going through the ssl layer. If you don't have firefox, then I am pretty sure Chrome also has something similar to FireBug built in.

Here's how to use firebug:

1. Open firebug
2. Click on the Console Tab
3. Reload the page
4. Any https errors will show in the console and tell you which resource is not working.

Hope this helps

Comment: could you be more specific?

Comment: Load up the page with the Net tab activated. Once the page is completed loading, hover over each entry and the GET entry will display the URL it is retrieving. You'll eventually find the ones that are being retrieved via HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Comment: do you think manualy check each one specificaly in the whole assets stack? What about some https filtering?

Comment: To add to @phantom's solution, you can right-click an entry in the Network tab and choose, "copy all as HAR". This will copy all the entries as a JSON-like object, which makes it easy to paste into an editor and Ctrl-F for "http:".
Can't believe there is no scheme-tab in the Developer Tools Network tab, though.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem but all the image, css and js references were https. But some were red. So I copied the url and only when I pasted them in their own browser tab did I find out that the server's certificate had expired. So that's another not obvious reason you might get that error.

Comment: Note that export is no longer available by default. You will an additional extension: http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/netexport/

Comment: Re: the comment by @Protectorone - if you right-click on the headers in the Network tab, you can now add 'Scheme' and then sort by it.

Comment: Chrome now shows this error if a form on your https page submits data to a non SSL destination, this doesn't show in the network tab but does show in the console. 
So Now it seems you need check both the network scheme column and the Chrome console.

Comment: The important part of this answer is that the warnings show up in the Firebug **CONSOLE** tab, and not the "Net" tab.

Answer (score 90):

I've just had this problem in Chrome also. I checked in the Network tab but all resources were loaded over https.

Solution: close Chrome and re-open.

Chrome must cache its secure-content detection so that even when you fix the problems the insecure content message won't disappear.

Comment: Closing chrome is overkill, you can just close the tab.

Comment: I have a love/hate relationship with Chrome - problems like this go under the "hate" column. -_- So much time wasted for nothing. Thank you for this solution, it worked for me.

Comment: @MjrKusanagi thanks for the trick..RESTART worked for me too..i couldn't see anything in the network tab or console errros..changed all the default option..realy wondering why it was not working..but got the green https:// in the address bar..

Comment: My issue was the <form> tag on my page.  Webkit's network debugger will not show you if your action parameter points to a non-secure url!

Answer (score 40):

I have nothing to do with the people providing this online script, but it's easy and can be bookmarked in any browser..  works well and quickly to solve the problem..  http://www.whynopadlock.com

Comment: Hey, that was really helpful, I coul'nt find the culprit until I tried that script and found out it was a google font linked with http instead of https!

Comment: This was the only thing that exposed the issue, thank you.  It turned out I had a <form> tag referencing an action on http - not https!

Answer (score 8):

In Google Chrome: You can view the offending resource in the `Console` tab of the `Inspect Element` window.

It will be listed as:

> The page at https://example.com/page displayed insecure content from **http**://example.com/resource

Of course you **might have to reload** the page with the `Inspect Element` window already open.

Comment: Network tab > right-click any column heading > click "Scheme"

Comment: @Costa: The problem with that approach is that it won't list content that Chrome blocked.  The solution in the answer shows both.

Comment: This is known as the "Console Drawer", and is opened by clicking the ">☰"  smbol near the top right of the inspector.

Comment: Chrome will also give this warning for forms on a page that submit to non-secure locations.

Comment: Great answer. I fixed all the http problems listed in my network tab. but the console showed me that I also had to fix a form target for a newsletter to make it use https. No form targets on an SSL page may target a non SSL page, apparently.

Answer (score 6):

One of the easiest ways to do it is to right-click the page in Firefox and select View Page Info. Then go to the Media tab and find anything that is loading from http instead of https.

Comment: That works great for images and the like, but often times it's a linked Javascript or CSS file causing the HTTPS to break.

Comment: This is the fastest solution to find the culprit link in a certain page. I think this is the best solution over all the solutions in this page.. Thank u

Comment: This does not work as it does not show javascripts which are loaded by other scripts. It shows only elements which are directly linked in the HTML

Answer (score 6):

We've scratched our own itch and wrote a tool that crawls your web-site and tells you what pages have non-SSL resources on them. You just need to enter the root URL of your web site – no need to check every page manually.

http://www.jitbit.com/sslcheck/

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that when I had this problem that a toolbar(uTorrent) was causing the error. I removed the toolbar and the error went away. Not sure why a toolbar would cause an error on my site, but no more problems here with the SSL certificate.

Answer (score 2):

To add to this I right-clicked on the column headings in the Network tab view and selected Protocol.

If you then click on the Protocol heading, the contents of the report will be grouped by HTTPS, etc

Comment: In Chrome v69, I think it is the "Scheme" column that would be more useful in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, you can find out which resources were loaded via http versus https by doing the following:

1) In Wrench menu, choose Tools > Developer tools

2) Click on "Resources" toolbar icon

3) Expand the Frames folder to see the different pages.  Expand the page whose resources you want to see.  The individual Resources for the page are then listed, broken down by Images, Scripts, and Stylesheets

4) To see the URL that was used to load that resource, just hover the mouse over the resource name and the URL will appear, either with http or https.  You can also click on an image name to see the image on the right side, along with its URL

Comment: Network tab > right-click any column heading > click "Scheme"

Comment: Great. Why do they call it Scheme instead of Protocol? :/

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has their own developer tool.

you can right click a page, inspect it.. and then click the "network" tab and reload the page. you'll see the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if any one will be checking this answer
Or you might have found the solution already, but anyway, my answer might help other people suffering from similar issue

http://www.whynopadlock.com/

This is the link that I used to check the insecure content /file which was being loaded to my page.

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered same behaviour in chrome (firefox showed a green lock), even though all resources were loaded via https.

The reason in my case was that the server supported broken (google poodle) SSLv3.

Setting ssl_protocols to exclude SSLv2 in nginx.conf like so

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
```

fixed the problem for me.

I consider it unfortunate that chrome doesn't make this reason more transparent. "this page loads some resources insecurely" is very misleading if not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to crawl your own site from your own desktop for a list of all reasources loaded (not loaded by javascript though, which is worth bearing in mind), if using windows you can use [Xenu's link sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html). Export the TSV file and then right click and open with excel, then sort by URL, you can then find those pesky http resources for all pages on the site!