# What protocol is loaded when using protocol-relative URLs?

Tags: url, protocols

I just started to test the idea behind "protocol less Urls".

The problem I´m looking to solve is: **on a https page I need to load an external css file from http.**

Doing this the "normal" way results in failure... the css file is blocked. (Just testing with chrome for now).

So my question is: **Will "protocol less Urls" load the file from http/https/both?**

Comment: Not sure but you can check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292697/find-out-what-resources-are-not-going-over-https).

Comment: This is a valid question

Comment: This seems to show up #1 in Google. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just for detailed answer

Comment: btw, protocol-relative URL is now an anti-pattern : http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're referring to URLs like `www.example.com/style.css`, that won't work because the protocol is completely missing; a browser will treat `www.example.com` as some kind of directory path name.

If you're referring to URLs like `//www.example.com/style.css`, that is a protocol-relative URL; it uses the same protocol as what the browser is already using to request the referring page. For example, if the browser had requested a page with `https://www.example.com`, then that URL will be requested over HTTPS and not HTTP.

Browser support for these URLs is generally pretty good; see the following questions:

- [Is it valid to replace http:// with // in a <script src="http://...">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)
- [Can I change all my http:// links to just //?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just)

Comment: So it will inherit the current protocol... so on my https page it will try to load the css from https?

Comment: That's correct. Your server just needs to be able to respond appropriately.

Comment: Hmm.. so is there some way to work around this? The second server does not have https

Comment: Why does the second server block if you try using `http://`? It sounds like something was misconfigured...

Comment: It´s not blocked by server but by the browser (chrome in this case)

Comment: does it work for loading css file in another css file using import rule?

Comment: @Krunal: It should work.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for notifying. I did checked this already and it worked great. +1