# SSL/HTTPS issue (no padlock icon) on Safari when using ngixn+unicorn

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, safari, unicorn

I have an application that runs on nginx+unicorn. This is how my server block looks like

```
upstream rtdev{
# fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
# to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a single worker for timing out).
server unix:/tmp/rtapp.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server{

listen                443 ssl; # default;
server_name           devapp.resolutiontweet.com;
root                  /home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/public;
client_max_body_size 12M;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate         xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx.crt;
ssl_certificate_key     xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx.key;

ssl_ciphers "AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

ssl_stapling on; # Requires nginx >= 1.3.7
ssl_stapling_verify on; # Requires nginx => 1.3.7

location / {
    access_log          off;

    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_redirect    off;
    proxy_headers_hash_max_size 8192;
    proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 256;

    proxy_pass          http://rtdev;


    #proxy_redirect      http://rtdev https://devapp.resolutiontweet.com;
   }
}
```

I'm running into a weird issue where Safari doesn't show 
the "Lock" symbol for the secure site. All other browsers show it (tested on Chrome and Firefox). Attaching screenshots for reference.

[image: Mozilla Firefox]
[image: Google Chrome]
[image: Safari]

Mozilla Firefox
Google Chrome
Safari
Modifying a few things in my server block fixes the issue, but the site doesn't load. For example changing,

`proxy_pass          http://rtdev; --> proxy_pass          https://rtdev;` 
resolves the issue, but nginx throws  501 error.

I would appreciate if anyone can throw light on how to resolve/debug the issue. Thanks.

EDIT: The certificates are chained properly. I verified the settings with a couple of third party sites and everything seems fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the reason and it has got nothing to do with my server configuration.

Apparently, an unsafe script was injected dynamically by one of the libraries I was using. The script was using **http** not **https**.

Firefox and Chrome give an indication that the page contains unsafe scripts, Safari on the other hand, doesn't give user any feedback and shows the page as unsecure.

I don't know what to say, whether to applaud Apple for being overly cautious or to blame it for any lack of visual feedback.

**References:**

[Find out what resources are not going over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292697/find-out-what-resources-are-not-going-over-https)

https://www.whynopadlock.com/