# padlock on safari mobile not showing persistently

Tags: iphone, ipad, ssl, https, safari

I'm having a strange issue with an HTTPS site where the padlock sometimes disappears on safari mobile (both iphone and ipad). Some pages are more consistent than others, but some times the same page would show a padlock and another time it will be gone...

example pages:

- https://m.frau-vintage.com (mostly showing padlock)
- https://m.frau-vintage.com/shopping-cart/ (mostly not showing padlock)

I tested those pages with https://www.whynopadlock.com (all green), https://www.jitbit.com/sslcheck/ (no issues). SSLLabs gives an [A- score](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=m.frau-vintage.com&hideResults=on). I was also using Firefox / Chrome (incl. mobile chrome) - and the padlock does seem to appear there consistently with no issues. I also traced all network connections using Chrome developer tools and there are no http connections, only https... I'm wondering what else could cause the padlock to disappear intermittently (and how to resolve this).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an unsafe script being injected dynamically by one of the libraries you are using specifically on these pages. The script might use http and not https.

This might help you: [Find out what resources are not going over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292697/find-out-what-resources-are-not-going-over-https)

Comment: the padlock seems to appear / disappear early on when the page is loaded. It could be some script, but when debugging this on Chrome or Firefox I didn't see any request to non-SSL resource. I couldn't get debugging working on the iphone unfortunately... Also - wouldn't an unsafe script remove the padlock on other browsers? why only Safari?

Comment: whilst this didn't solve the problem, it was the most plausible direction, so I awarded the bounty... Unfortunately my question still remains unanswered :(

Answer (score -1):

It seems the https://m.frau-vintage.com and the shopping-cart URL are going to different HTTPS servers (or atleast presenting different certificates).
Please check the certificate on the shopping cart server is matching the one on the on the https://m.frau-vintage.com.

Comment: it's a sub-folder on the same domain / server. How can it use a different certificate? (even with SNI, as far as I'm aware, the certificate is tied to the domain name, not a sub-folder)

Comment: Yes, certificates are tied to a host or host+domain only, or a wildcard of a domain. On the net Im on I can only see that one of the URL has certificate that doesnt match the URL. Maybe you have a redirect pointing to non-HTTPS url och different site.

Comment: Maybe you're using an old browser that doesn't support SNI? As I mentioned, I've run various tests, including for the SSL certificate and it seems to be ok... I don't think the problem is with the certificate, but happy to be proven wrong if it means this will resolve the issue with mobile safari.